# Error while adding multiple Views to a LinearLayout programatically

Tags: android

I was trying to add a `View` multiple times by using a for loop, but I was getting an error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

My XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_display_list"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout">
</LinearLayout>
```

My class file

```
ViewGroup ll = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.root_layout);
TextView tv = (TextView) new TextView(this);
tv.setText("helloworld");
tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

//adding views in loop
for(int i=0;i<=5;i++)
{
    ll.addView(tv);
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You're trying to add the same `TextView` five times. Move everything except the `findViewById()` line to inside your loop. And you probably don't want `MATCH_PARENT` params for both dimensions.

Comment: Why is it so? why to create the object 5 times when we can create it once and use it 5 times?

Comment: That doesn't really make any sense. If you want five `TextView`s, you need to create five of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add the same `View` multiple times to the same layout.

The following should work:

```
ViewGroup ll = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.root_layout);

for(int i=0; i<=5; i++)
{
    TextView tv = (TextView) new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("helloworld");
    tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    ll.addView(tv);
}
```

Also, setting either the height or the width (maybe both, depending on the orientation of your `LinearLayout`) of the `TextView` to `WRAP_CONTENT`  might make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You should use LinearLayout, and need to create textview and params everytime, because you can't add single view multiple times -

```
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root_layout);

          //adding views in loop
          for(int i=0;i<=5;i++)
          {
             TextView tv = (TextView) new TextView(this);
             tv.setText("helloworld");
             ll.addView(tv, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
          }
```

Hope it will help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for(int i=0;i<=5;i++){
    ViewGroup ll = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.root_layout);
    TextView tv = (TextView) new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("helloworld");
    tv.setLayoutParams(new        LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    ll.addView(tv);
```

}

Comment: What are you asking here? Please explain.

Answer (score -1):

Try it, may it help..

```
 //adding views in loop
    for(int i=0;i<=5;i++)
    {
    if(tv.getParent()!=null)
    {
        ((ViewGroup)tv.getParent()).removeView(tv);
    }
    ll.addView(tv); 
}
```

thanks..